# Sitecore non administrator user show hidden items

Tags: sitecore

I have created some Sitecore users who are not administrators and assigned them few roles. When these users access the Sitecore portal as default they are not shown hidden items and they have to go to view tab and configure it manually. Is there a way I can configure these users to view hidden items by default by doing some configurations to a user role shared between these users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is retrieved by `Sitecore.Shell.UserOptions.View.ShowHiddenItems` property which gets this data from `UserProfile` (or from `RegistryCache` if the profile was already loaded).

User profile information is stored for every user separately and saved in database in binary column. There is no way of getting this option from user role.

Still you can write a script that will loop through all users in the role you mentioned and set the value in profile of those users:

```cs
public static void SetHiddenItemsValue(User user)
{
    string key = "/Current_User/UserOptions.View.ShowHiddenItems";
    string value = "true";

    if (!(user != null))
        return;
    key = StringUtil.Left(key, 250);
    key = key.Replace("Current_User", user.Name);
    user.Profile[key] = value;
    user.Profile.Save();
    RegistryCache registryCache = CacheManager.GetRegistryCache(Sitecore.Context.Site);
    if (registryCache == null)
        return;
    registryCache.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative option from Maras is you could possibly hook into the `security:loggedin` event and set that value.

Your class needs to inherit from `Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInProcessor`
That'll need to do something like the following:

```
public override void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
{
    var user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(args.Username, true);
    var key = "/" + args.Username + "/UserOptions.View.ShowHiddenItems";

    // if user needs to be in a specific role only, check that here
    // if (user.IsInRole("yourrolename"))
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Profile[key]))
    {
        user.Profile[key] = "true";
        user.Profile.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree. This is an option as well. Benefit of your solution is that it will work for new users assigned to this role. Drawback is that it will be executed after every login action for all users. Anyway +1